# Bokeh - how to update slider min, max values with Select widget?

Tags: python, select, widget, slider, bokeh

Please, any idea how to update the slider min and max values, index_min and index_max, with users Select widget? For example, when  u1 is selected, the min and max values of the slider should be 2586 and 2836.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.layouts import column, layout
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, Slider
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [2586, 2836, 2986, 3269, 3702],
                   'X': [120, 210, 80, 98, 40],
                   'Y': [230, 40, 33, 122, 10],
                   'User': ['u1', 'u1', 'u2', 'u2', 'u2'],
                   'img': ['tree1.png', 'tree2.jpg', 'tree3.jpg', 'tree4.jpg','tree5.jpg']})

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(time=[], x=[], y=[], user=[], img=[]))

options = sorted(set(df['User']))
user_options = ['Please select ...'] + options
users = Select(title="User:", value=user_options[0], options=user_options)

index_min = df['Time'].min()
index_max = df['Time'].max()
index = Slider(start=index_min, end=index_max, value=index_max , step=1, title="Time Index")

def select_user():
    user_val = users.value
    selected = df[(df.Time <= index.value)]
    if (user_val != ""):
        selected = selected[selected.User.str.contains(user_val)==True]
    return selected

def update():
    dfnew = select_user()
    source.data = dict(time=dfnew['Time'], x=dfnew['X'], y=dfnew['Y'], user=dfnew['User'], img=dfnew['img'])


controls = [users, index]
for control in controls:
    control.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())


p = figure(plot_width = 600, plot_height = 600)
p.circle(x="x", y="y", source=source, legend='user')


update() # initial load of the data

l = layout(column(users, index, p))

curdoc().add_root(l)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

```py
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, Slider

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [2586, 2836, 2986, 3269, 3702, 1, 2],
                   'X': [120, 210, 80, 98, 40, 0, 1],
                   'Y': [230, 40, 33, 122, 10, 1, 2],
                   'User': ['u1', 'u1', 'u2', 'u2', 'u2', 'u3', 'u4'],
                   'img': ['tree1.png', 'tree2.jpg', 'tree3.jpg', 'tree4.jpg', 'tree5.jpg', 'x', 'x']})

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(time=[], x=[], y=[], user=[], img=[]))

user_options = [('', 'Please select ...')] + [(o, o) for o in sorted(set(df['User']))]
users = Select(title="User:", value=user_options[0][0], options=user_options)

index = Slider(start=0, end=1, value=0, step=1, title="Time Index")


def filter_by_user(user):
    if user:
        return df[df['User'] == user]
    return df


def on_user_change(attr, old, new):
    selected = filter_by_user(new)
    start = selected['Time'].min()
    end = selected['Time'].max()
    index.update(start=start,
                 end=end + 1 if start == end else end,
                 value=start,
                 disabled=start == end)


users.on_change('value', on_user_change)


def on_index_change(attr, old, new):
    selected = filter_by_user(users.value)
    dfnew = selected[selected['Time'] <= new]
    # Note: if you rename your df columns to all lower-case, then you can just use `ColumnDataSource.from_df()`.
    source.data = dict(time=dfnew['Time'], x=dfnew['X'], y=dfnew['Y'], user=dfnew['User'], img=dfnew['img'])


index.on_change('value', on_index_change)

# Just to populate the initial data.
on_user_change(None, None, '')

curdoc().add_root(column(users, index))
```

Comment: Thank Eugene! Works for a data frame with two users, but data is changing, number of users will increase. I have just added controls update on_change to my initial code, and a circle plot to see the changes with Select and Slider. My code works just fine, but the displayed values for Slider min and max remains the same. I thought maybe it's possible to  update the variable  index_min and index_max, and therefore the displayed values will also change.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. My code doesn't care about the number of users. And it does successfully change the max and min values of the slider in `on_user_change`. If you have a scenario where my code doesn't work for you, please update the question.

Comment: In your code, I have changed the user value in the last row, from u2 to u3. The slider doesn't work for u3.

Comment: Ah, that's because there are no min and max values then, just a single value. Bokeh does not support that - you should see errors in the JS console. I've updated the `on_user_change` function in my answer to just disable the slider if that's the case. It may still result in errors about min being the same as max, but you can ignore them.

Comment: Just perfect, updates source and slider start/end displayed values! Thank you for your help and learning opportunity!